# Convert a bit to Base64 character

Tags: java, base64

I need to **convert a binary String** (*"110100"*, 52 in decimal) to its corresponding **Base64 character**, that I know is "0". Is any way in Java to do that? I was reading multiple base 64 guides but I cant reach the answer.

For clarification, the conversion table is here: https://www.lifewire.com/base64-encoding-overview-1166412 (Base64 Encoding Table section) I want having the 52, convert it to "0" char.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: There are any number of base64 libraries. Is there a reason you cant use them?

Comment: I know the java.util.Base64Encoder and java.util.Base64Decoder. But if i simply pass the "110100" string as argument, i cant reach the desired value.

Comment: How about just using `Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt("...", 2), 64)` ?

Comment: I cant pass a String to Integer.toString("...", 64). If i do Integer.toString(52, 64) it dont work.

Comment: @Ecto Max radix for `Integer.toString()` is **36**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a byte is 8 bits long and Base64 makes up its values by grabbing only 6 bits the simplest way I can think of is appending two characters at the beginning of your desired character and taking only the last character of the result:

```
String encode = String.format("00%s", (char) Integer.parseInt("110100", 2));
String encoded = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(encode.getBytes()));
System.out.println(encoded.charAt(encoded.length() - 1));
// Prints: 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked!. Im trying to razone it myself, specially the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to convert your binary string into a byte array.  There are a number of posts on how to accomplish this but in pseudo code it would look like the following.

```
  Read up to 4 characters;

  Byte.parseByte(chars, 2);

  Append to byte array;
```

Then you can use Base64.Encoder to encode the bytes.